# How do i download files using flash cs6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, action, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I have a project with  four different buttons in flash which will download doc files locally. Since I am new to flash scripting i don't know how to start with. Can anyone help to start with that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
private var request:URLRequest;  
private var localRef:FileReference;  

protected function buttonClick():void  
{  
  request = new URLRequest("http://www.yourdomain.com/soundbyte.mp3");  
  localRef = new FileReference();    

  try  
  {  
     // Prompt and downlod file  
     localRef.download( request );  
  }  
  catch (error:Error)  
  {  
     trace("Unable to download file.");  
  }  
}
```

You should give a read to [FileReference Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) (If you are using AIR i suggest you to use [File Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) instead).

Comment: what kind of error? buttonClick function must be the callback for  a Mouse.CLICK event to work.